# How can i use sql query for the following

Tags: sql-server

My data table `sampletime` in one column and sample value in another column contain data like follow

```
sampletime            value
----------------------------
2016-03-02 08:31:14     1 
2016-03-02 09:31:14     2
2016-03-02 12:31:14     3
2016-03-04 08:31:14     4
2016-03-04 09:31:14     5
2016-03-05 08:31:14     3
```

I need two minimum sample time in each day. How can I group?

Query

```
SELECT rn.sampletime AS stime 
FROM   rn_qos_data_0007 rn 
       INNER JOIN s_qos_data qos 
               ON qos.table_id = rn.table_id 
                  AND qos.qos = 'QOS_CPU_USAGE' 
                  AND Substring(qos.origin, 1, 4) = 'A0C3' 
                  AND qos.host = '10.98.48.100' 
WHERE  rn.sampletime BETWEEN '2016/01/01' AND '2016/06/22' 
GROUP  BY rn.sampletime
```

Comment: You start by providing enough details to make your question an actual question. As posted this in not answerable. You can however improve it. Take a look here. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Clearly, grouping by a `datetime` will not give you figures per day. You need to cast to a `date` as Prdp has shown. Then pulling out the 2 minimal records would be done via `row_number()`, as they also said, or by a correlated subquery mechanism such as`cross apply`.

Answer (score 0):

You need `ROW_NUMBER` window function

```
Select * From
(
select row_number()over(partition by cast(sampletime as date) order by sampletime) RN,*
From ..
) A
Where RN <=2
```

Comment: select rn.sampletime as stime from RN_QOS_DATA_0007 rn
      INNER JOIN S_QOS_DATA qos on qos.table_id=rn.table_id and qos.QOS='QOS_CPU_USAGE'
      AND SUBSTRING(qos.origin, 1, 4)='A0C3' AND qos.host ='10.98.48.100'
      WHERE rn.sampletime  between  '2016/01/01' 
      AND '2016/06/22' 
      group by  rn.sampletime

Comment: this is my query and gives one record(TIME) per day but i need two records(last two TIME) per day

Comment: @SureshSofty Put stuff like that in your question in the first place, not sprinkled in comments that people might not notice. Comments' lifetime is not guaranteed.